# How to disable auto uninstalling of the development apps, Tizen TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I have an app for Tizen TV (SDK 2.4), installed in Developer Mode. After the TV reboot, or several app closes, TV starts an update process and uninstalls my app. Disabling of the Smart TV auto update feature wasn't helpful and I can't find any expiration date preferences in config.xml. Does somebody know how to save the app installed for future showing/testing? Thank you.

Comment: how are you deploying app on TV through USB or any other method

Comment: @Gagu USB and by network connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after all that time I wrote to 1:1 Q&A at http://seller.samsungapps.com/ . The answer is, unfortunately:

> I'm sorry to tell you but excpet the application store, there is no other option to keep installed application on TV.